# Storing and comparing multidimensional vectors

Tags: algorithm, vector, database-design

I have multidimensional vectors with n-degrees. What is the best way to handle them.

- Storage (what is the best mode to store them, SQL, Mongo, Document?)
- Comparison (How do I compare two of them and find similarity).

Example:

```
a{1,3,4,1,-1},
b{2,3,3,0,0},
c{2,3,2,8,9}
```

If we compare the above two, `a` and `b` are more similar.

How do do this in large scale? I want to store thousands of such vectors.

Similarily can be the vector distance. [image: Vector Distance]

Comment: Is `n` fixed or can it vary? Does the storage have to handle vectors with different values of `n`?

Comment: Why are `a` and `b` 'more similar' (than what)? What is the algorithm to calculate similarity? Do you want to calculate similarity between every pair of vectors?

Comment: Similarity is the vector distance (Updated question). And yeah, n is constant.

Comment: If `n` is constant, you could store vectors in a table with `n` columns, one for each dimension. What about my other questions?

Comment: I want to find the Euclidean distance between each of the vectors. I don't that can be done if we store them in tables, see the equation I have added.

Answer (score 2):

My bet for storage would be on a Graph database, like Neo4j. You can calculate the Euclidean distance (and probably implement k-means clustering to get closest points) using Cypher query.

For details on implementation, check out the below articles --

- http://heidi.morkland.org/tag/neo4j/
- http://mikelam.azurewebsites.net/beer-recommendations-with-user-based-collaborative-filtering/